# Openapi generator cannot generate query param with enum

Tags: java, generator, openapi

I'm trying to generate a service that has enum as query parameter, but it keeps generating it wrong.
Here's the part of yaml:

```
      name: language
      in: query
      description: language
      schema:
        type: string
        enum:
        - en
        - de
```

and I'm using it in parameters:

```
        - $ref: '#/components/parameters/language'
```

The error that I get is:

```
[ERROR] .../api/TestApi.java:[110,65] illegal start of type
[ERROR] .../api/TestApi.java:[110,66] ')' expected
[ERROR] .../api/TestApi.java:[110,82] ';' expected
```

Here's what the code looks like:

```
public Response getByLanguage( @PathParam("id") Long id, , allowableValues="en, de" @QueryParam("language") String language
```

And here's my plugin:

```
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
                    <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>5.0.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <inputSpec>${basedir}/src/main/resources/openapi.yaml</inputSpec>
                        <output>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/java</output>
                        <generatorName>jaxrs-resteasy-eap</generatorName>
                        <modelPackage>com.openapi.example.model</modelPackage>
                        <apiPackage>com.openapi.example.api</apiPackage>
                        <generateSupportingFiles>false</generateSupportingFiles>
                        <configOptions>
                            <sourceFolder>openapi</sourceFolder>
                            <dateLibrary>java8</dateLibrary>
                            <interfaceOnly>true</interfaceOnly>
                            <java8>true</java8>
                            <serializableModel>true</serializableModel>
                            <useTags>true</useTags>
                            <performBeanValidation>true</performBeanValidation>
                            <useBeanValidation>true</useBeanValidation>
                        </configOptions>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                            <id>generate</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>generate</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
```

The only way I've managed to get it to work is to make it as an array of enum values, but that's not what I need here.

EDIT:
dependencies I have defined in the project:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.shared</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-analyzer</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.8</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.5</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.3</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 4):

Multiple long standing enum bugs exist in the generators (for all languages as far as I can tell).

For example https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/4300

But also .. https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/2645

Answer (score 1):

Try out with below demo yaml.

Enums should be defined as enum: [en, de].

```
openapi: 3.0.2
info: {title: Demo Info., description: Demo Description., version: 1.0.0}
servers:
- {url: 'https://something.com', description: Demo Description.}
paths:
  /something:
    post:
      tags: [Something]
      requestBody:
        required: true
        content:
          application/json:
            schema: {$ref: '#/components/schemas/SomethingRequest'}
      parameters:
      - {$ref: '#/components/parameters/language'}
      responses:
        200:
          description: OK
          content:
            application/json:
              schema: {$ref: '#/components/schemas/SomethingResponse'}
components:
  parameters:
    language:
      name: language
      schema:
        type: string
        enum: [en, de]
        default: en
      in: query
  schemas:
    SomethingRequest:
      properties:
        demo: {type: string}
    SomethingResponse:
      properties:
        demo: {type: string}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that also doesn't work:
`public Response somethingPost(@ApiParam(value = "" ,required=true) @NotNull @Valid SomethingRequest somethingRequest, , allowableValues="en, de" @DefaultValue("en") @QueryParam("language") String language,@Context SecurityContext securityContext);`
as you can see, there's that double comma again

Comment: @StopTheRain It generated fine for me. May be need to have close look into the maven configuration. Could you update question with minimal POM details like dependencies you are using.

Comment: I updated the question with all the dependencies I have. The only other thing defined in the POM is the plugin I provided. Could you please send me your plugin configuration?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
...
paths:
...
        - name: semesterType
          in: query
          required: true
          schema:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/SemesterType'
...
components:
  schemas:
    SemesterType:
      type: string
      enum:
        - SOMMERSEMESTER
        - WINTERSEMESTER
```

Comment: Just adding note, this file looks like openAPI v3 schema, I tried simmilar approach with swagger v2 schema but no luck.
And yes, this finally works for me, now just find a way why YAML/JSON generator cannot add enums as referenced objects first

Answer (score 0):

It depends what generator you are using but jaxrs-resteasy-eap is broken when using enums in query parameters.

I think [this](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/commit/5e92ec1b4c3743026ade9a55bf9345f894877f15#diff-1b2fac13dd3086346026a61b6c76dbe6af49c8f70de616c7cbe92bfe7a83289e) commit is causing the problem.

As a temporary fix in my project I edited the queryParams.mustache template file to as this:

```
{{#isQueryParam}}{{#useBeanValidation}}{{>beanValidationQueryParams}}{{/useBeanValidation}}{{^isContainer}}{{#allowableValues}}@ApiParam(value = "{{{description}}}"{{#required}},required=true{{/required}}, {{> allowableValues }}){{/allowableValues}}{{#defaultValue}} @DefaultValue("{{{.}}}"){{/defaultValue}}{{/isContainer}} @QueryParam("{{baseName}}") {{{dataType}}} {{paramName}}{{/isQueryParam}}
```

Just noticed that there are also [github issue](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/4376) of this. The recommendation of removing the allowableValues from queryParams.mustache might be the correct way to go:

```
{{#isQueryParam}}{{#useBeanValidation}}{{>beanValidationQueryParams}}{{/useBeanValidation}}{{^isContainer}}{{#defaultValue}} @DefaultValue("{{{.}}}"){{/defaultValue}}{{/isContainer}} @QueryParam("{{baseName}}") {{{dataType}}} {{paramName}}{{/isQueryParam}}
```

It depends how you are using the generator how to use own templates.

I am using it from npm @openapitools/openapi-generator-cli
There you can apply your own templates by adding -t/--template-dir  option into your generate command. Here is mine as example:

```
npx @openapitools/openapi-generator-cli generate -t=templates/jaxrs -i openapi.yaml -o generated/jaxrs -g jaxrs-resteasy-eap -c config-jaxrs.yaml
```

I just copied my modified queryParams.mustache to root of templates/jaxrs and the generated api functions did not have double comma syntax problems anymore:

```
public Response getPets( @ApiParam(value = "My param description", allowableValues="AA, BB, CC") @QueryParam("petType") PetType petType,@Context SecurityContext securityContext);
```

I haven't used these files yet, so I don't know if everything is correct, but atleast the syntax is correct now.

More info here: [templating documentation](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/templating)